# Setting up Bulk App Deployment on SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, deployment, app, bulk

I'm trying to perform an App Deployment to all the site in a Site Collection using the SharePoint 2013 deployment feature

[Tenancies and deployment scopes for SharePoint Add-ins](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/tenancies-and-deployment-scopes-for-sharepoint-add-ins)

I'm unable to see the deployment button on the App when I hover over the ellipsis.

My account is a Site Collection Administrator.

Could someone lend a hand if there is a permission/feature that I'm missing?